# Thread.Sleep, AJAX, Session, and request queuing in web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, multithreading

The issue I'm having is my code is creating duplicate data in the database. I believe the following is what is occurring (even though it ought to be impossible):

We have a page which has a long running task which is kicked off by an UpdatePanel (in this case, triggered by a timer). This task grabs data from a web service, deletes the local copy (actually just sets an IsDeleted flag, not a sql DELETE), and creates a new object and commits it to the DB.

I believe that core cause of the duplication is that the user is closing/reloading the tab before the AJAX request returns and is starting the process anew. As the first AJAX request is still processing, the second one starts. The logs back this up.

However, I know this should be impossible! The page in question reads and writes to Session, and EnableSessionState is not set to ReadOnly or Disabled. The requests should have been queued and not interleaved. However the logs clearly show the following:

Thread 1 gets halfway done with processing (deletes half the data and creates new objects) then the web service starts to lag.

Thread 2 kicks off, grabbing data which has been half updated by thread 1. This half updates fine (because it is just like a regular data refresh thus far from Thread 2's perspective; the same as if we had queued the requests)

Thread 1 finishes, deleting the last half of the data, creating new objects.

Thread 2 finishes, deleting the last half of the data (the same as thread 1 has just done, but the ORM we are using won't complain) and creates new objects which are duplicates of the objects thread 1 just created.

I know about half a dozen ways to fix the problem; that isn't my question. My question is: Is there anything special about long running (minutes long) processes in ASP.NET which would allow the processes to interleave? How about AJAX requests?

The only thing I can think of is that we do something in a DLL like the following:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now();
DateTime until = now.AddMinutes(3);
while(until > now){
    var result = makeWebServiceRequest();
    if(result.error == 0){
         //process data
    }
    //Try again in 10 seconds
    System.Thread.Threading.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Is it possible that while a thread is sleeping, it doesn't count towards the session queue, especially since its in an external assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `executionTimeout` in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Since your requests are taking longer than the default 110 seconds, this may be what you experience - ASP.NET releasing the lock on `Session` and letting queued requests to proceed.

Comment: So, what I'm betting is that while it is possible for a thread to get shut down after the executionTimeout, there is no guarantee that it will be?